# How to put in a layout in Android as many imagebuttons as ids existing?

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-layout, android-sqlite

I have to do an application about buying tickets for events and parties. In the Home layout(once the user is logging) it has to bring,get all the places in which there will be an event. For this, I want to create as many imagebuttons as places registered in the sqlite database are(ids) in order to make the user click on one of these imagebutton(events/parties) and then go to another view giving more specific information about this one blah blah blah. The problem is that I don't know how to do this, so I would really appreciate our help. Thanks!

Comment: You need a listview or recycler view. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html Given that you have images, I suggest recyclerview given that it is more efficient due to the ViewHolder pattern.

Comment: You should learn basic Android programming first.